# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get' random stuff api python

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to make an AI Chatbot using the [Random stuff](https://nerdguyahmad.gitbook.io/randomstuff/) api and whenever I try to make one, I always get this error (I am using replit.com to host):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 5, in <module>
    response = client.get_ai_response("Hi there!")
  File "/home/runner/ChatBot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/randomstuff/client.py", line 254, in get_ai_response
    message=response[0].get('response'),
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

The code is here:

```py
    import randomstuff

    client = randomstuff.Client(api_key="xxx")

    response = client.get_ai_response("Hi there!")
    print(response.message)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this API has been deprecated:

> Hey there, we have deprecated our old version and now we can only be operated through RapidApi. Kindly headover to https://api.pgamerx.com/new for more information

You should switch to the new version since the old one no longer works.

Incidentally, this is also why you get the error, since any call to the old API would return the above string, which obviously doesn't have a `get()` function.

Comment: Okay so how would i install it?

Comment: This should get you started: https://rapidapi.com/blog/how-to-use-an-api/. They use a different API as the example, but it should be applicable here as well.

Comment: Is there any code should i replace with my existing code for it to work?

Comment: Since you would be directly calling a REST Api endpoint as shown in the post instead of using a package, you will have to replace all code that depends on the `randomstuff` package. So that is pretty much everything you have written so far...